# Adjoints in occupation number representation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, conventions

I am having some trouble understanding how to compute things in occupation number representation. I believe my problem is only implicitly dealt with in the notes I have read. A simple example should suffice to deal with the general case as well I believe, so consider
$$\mid 0,2 \rangle$$
What is the adjoint of this ket? Is it $\langle 0,2 \mid$ or $\langle 2,0 \mid$ ?
This question arises as I concerned that I do not fully compute how to compute things like 
$$\langle 0,2 \mid H \mid 2,0 \rangle$$ 
where $H$ would be some Hamiltonian (or any function really).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Vectors (which kets are) don't have [*adjoints*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermitian_adjoint), they have [*duals*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_space#Finite-dimensional_case).
2. Whether the dual of $\lvert n_1,\dots,n_n\rangle$ is denoted by $\langle n_1,\dots,n_n\rvert$ or $\langle n_n,\dots,n_1 \rvert$ is entirely conventional.

Comment: 2) which is most common?

Comment: @sandstone: I would always write my first variant, and I think most others would, too.

Comment: I've never seen the second variant in practice. The meaning of the placeholders should generally remain the same for bra and ket vectors. The second variant is, if not incorrect, then at least confusing.